# Limit of probability question

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

> Assume for all finite $r>r_0$ that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A}_{r,n})=0,$$
>   where $\mathcal{A}_{r,n}$ is an event on some random variables, and $n$ and $r$ are deterministic variables. How to prove the following?
>   $$\lim_{n,r\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A}_{r,n})=0.$$

This is a part of a bigger problem. I need to prove the second equation but I have proved the first one. Is the second equation always true? If yes, how can I prove that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily true. Consider for example the case that

$$
\mathbb P(\mathcal{A}_{r,n}) = \frac{r}{r + n}
$$
Then clearly
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P(\mathcal{A}_{r,n}) = 0
$$
for every $r$ but
$$
\lim_{r,n \to \infty} \mathbb P(\mathcal{A}_{r,n}) \neq 0,
$$
since
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty} \mathbb P(\mathcal{A}_{m,m}) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: The idea is good but, for a more convincing argument, you might want to replace $$\frac rn$$ which takes values greater than $1$, by $$\frac r{r+n}$$ since the latter is always in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Did Sure, that would work. But, as I've said, it doesn't matter what $\mathbb P(\mathcal A_{r,n})$ is for $r \le n$ anyway since neither limit is affected by that.

Comment: Please read more carefully: the trouble with your example is when $r>n$, and **you need this regime since you are considering limits when $r\to\infty$**, for $n$ fixed.

Comment: @Did I don't need to consider those limits since I already get different limits for sequences with $r \le n$. But for the sake of clarity, I've edited it anyway.

Comment: Thank you. It helped to understand this. But, I realized the real problem I want to solve is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643189/limit-of-probability-question-2 . Can you take a look at that too?

Comment: @Did Can you see the new problem too?

Comment: @Su20200 Yep, I've answered it.