# Limit of probability question 2

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

> Assume for all finite $r>r_0$ that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A}_{r,n})=0,$$
>   where $\mathcal{A}_{r,n}$ is an event on some random variables, and $n$ and $r$ are deterministic variables. How to prove the following?
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\lim_{r\to\infty} \mathcal{A}_{r,n})=0.$$

This is a part of a bigger problem. I need to prove the second equation but I have proved the first one. Is the second equation always true? If yes, how can I prove that?

Comment: @Did Note that this is not duplicate,  they are two different questions. Please read the problem statements and think more before you mark something as a duplicate.

Comment: @Did this is your second mistake about me when marking duplicate.

Comment: Sure. When you will take the time to make a pause of about, say, 5 minutes in the stream of small variations of questions you are posting to the site, none of them being actually the one you mean to ask, let me suggest that you use these 5 minutes to take a honest and hard look at your past questions and wonder how they help to establish the site as a repository of knowledge (never heard the phrase? why am I not surprised?). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, this isn't necessarily true. Consider the case that
$$
\mathbb P(\mathcal A_{r,n}) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{, if } r > n \\
0 & \text{, otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you again, and you are right. Can you tell me under what conditions we can conclude the second equation from the first? Can I share the real problem with you?

Comment: @Su20200 Well, there are such properties but it's impossible to tell which one might help you with the given information. If you want to post the problem, I'd suggest posting it as a separate question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72922/discussion-on-answer-by-stefan-mesken-limit-of-probability-question-2).